# An app for looking at sound levels for surround sound channels?

Tags: macos, audio

I have been creating 5.1 surround sound files from Apple Compressor, but need a way to visually see that the different channels are all working properly in the final file. I can't test with a physical surround sound speaker set-up.

Is there an app that can show the sound levels for each channel, like you can with mono/stereo files in Audacity?

I don't have access to a full video editor like Final Cut Pro, or Avid. I would happily pay for a smaller audio utility that lets you do this.

Comment: I don't use Audacity, but a quick Google tells me it can do 5.1

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a hardware/software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Soundtrack Pro` from `Final Cut Studio 2009`. This is simple and robust application. There's surround 5.1 under its hood and moderate set of audio professional tools.

Comment: Thank you Andy,  that's a great tip. As Tetsujin mentioned above,  Audacity can also do it, although not as well as the older Sountrack Pro.